# ffmpeg for archival and convertibility

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a couple hundred gigs of *.dv files. I'd like to convert them to H.264 *or something else* ***or even leave them alone***. The purpose is archival, with an eye to maximum convertibility especially to DVD. The content is family videos.

Would this be fine?

```
ffmpeg -i input.dv \
    -c:v libx264 -preset slower \
    -crf 17 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    output.mp4
```

I went with the `slower` preset because encoding time isn't an issue and I'd like a smaller file size. crf 17 is for least-lossy while being widely playable. I read somewhere that yuv420p is needed for some Quicktime players.

Should I throw in `-c:a aac` for AAC audio? The audio is voice only, no need for music-hall quality.

I looked at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 for previous research and that's where I got those settings, but it is silent on the audio settings.

Edited: My priorities, in order of importance, are:

1. Compatibility
2. Losslessness (doesn't have to be 100% lossless, hence crf of 17 and not 0)
3. File size

Most of the input files say this:

```
[lavf] stream 0: video (dvvideo), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (pcm_s16le), -aid 0
VIDEO:  [dvsd]  720x480  0bpp  29.970 fps  25000.0 kbps (3051.8 kbyte/s)
Selected video codec: [ffdv] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg DV)
AUDIO: 32000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 1024.0 kbit/100.00% (ratio: 128000->128000)
Selected audio codec: [pcm] afm: pcm (Uncompressed PCM)
```

Output from ffmpeg:

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Archival formats

For archival purposes keep the original format if possible. This avoids [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

The more open-source aware members of the digital archival community are advocating the FFV1 + FLAC in Matroska, so you may have encountered this combination in your research. It a losslessly compressed combination of formats, and is an excellent choice for large organizations. But for personal use it may be overkill and the files will be bigger than the original DV files.

If storage space is a priority then you'll need to convert to a lossy format.

## Would this [command] be fine?

**Yes**, if you want the output to be high quality H.264 with AAC audio. This will be widely compatible by most players.

Only recommendation is to increase the audio bitrate somewhat with `-b:a 192k` since you want it to be semi-archival.

If the file size is still way too big then:

- Reduce the quality by using a higher `-crf`, or
- Use a newer (but much slower) encoder such as libx265. However this will output HEVC (H.265) video format which may not be compatible with your player/device/browser. See [FFmpeg Wiki: HEVC/H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

Comment: As much as I'd like to keep the original format, I had to convert it for editing anyway. That's how I ended up with the big DV files. I don't know what FFv1 is, but if it's one of those open source things that's great in principle but not widely adopted, I won't want to use it. I think I'll stick with the H.264 and maybe 128k audio. File size is a consideration, but compatibility is a higher priority.

Comment: @Satya Then use H.264 + AAC in MP4.

Comment: Thanks @llogan. Also, just added the output of mplayer for the input files. Probably doesn't matter, as I'll use H.264 and AAC anyway.

Comment: BTW re the open source thing, I'm on Ubuntu and I'd like to stick with OSS free/libre etc but not at the cost of losing precious family videos.